# dynamic bootstrap progress bar in angularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a web app in which i want to show progress bar depend on the data from my sql server,

for example i am getting my data like`(40)` in my progress bar width of my progress bar sould be `40%` and if my data is `70` width of my progress bar should be `70%`

here is my static progress bar

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
        aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
        <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

i am using angularJS so, my data is coming in my controller,

what i need to do to make my progress bar dynamic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try this

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Basic Progress Bar</h2>
<div class="progress">
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{value}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:{{value}}%">
  <span class="sr-only">{{value}}% Complete</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and in script write in controller and value from sql server to `value` variable  `$scope.value= variable`

```
$scope.value= 'sql data variable';
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that aria-valuenow attribute is itself dynamic, you can use this:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{progressValue}}"
        aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" ng-style="{'width':progressValue}">
        <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

In your AngularJS code:

```
..... function(data) {
 $scope.progressValue = data; // or something else depending upon your app logic.
//....
```